# where this series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the series $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6j^2-5j+1}$$
I am completely stuck and do not  understand the answer from my book which is $\pi^2/36-1$. I need explanation and different approach how this result is gained. Thanks

Comment: That answer is not correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Did you simply work out the answer, or is there something that allows you to say the answer can't be what the OP gave, just by looking at the series?

Comment: The first term of the series is $1$, so the sum is greater than $1$. The proposed answer is not only less than $1$, it is negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite your series as :
\begin{align}
\tag{1}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6j^2-5j+1}&=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3j-1)(2j-1)}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac2{2j-1}-\frac3{3j-1}\\
\tag{2}&=-2+3+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{j-\frac 12}-\frac1{j-\frac 13}\\
&=1-\psi\left(1-\frac 12\right)+\psi\left(1-\frac 13\right)\\
\tag{3}&=1+2\ln(2)-\frac{3\ln(3)}2+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\\
&\approx 1.645275610234835007\\
\end{align}
using the [special values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values) of the digamma function (or the [Gauss digamma sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem)) and the resolution method exposed in the excellent [Abramowitz and Stegun $(6.8)$](http://www.iopb.res.in/~somen/abramowitz_and_stegun/page_264.htm).

Here a more 'elementary' derivation is possible if we observe that for any integer $n>1$ :
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{j-\frac 1n}-\frac1{j}&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1x^{j-\frac 1n-1}-x^{j-1}\;dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(x^{k-1/n}-x^{k}\right)\;dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{-1/n}-1}{1-x}\;dx\\
\text{setting}\ x:=y^n\ \text{ we get :}\\
&=n\int_0^1 \frac{y^{-1}-1}{1-y^n}y^{n-1}\;dy\\
&=n\int_0^1 \frac{y^{n-2}-y^{n-1}}{1-y^n}\;dy\\
\text{that may be solved using}&\text{ partial fractions.}
\end{align}
From $(2)$ we need :
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{j-1/2}-\frac1{j-1/3}&=2\int_0^1 \frac{1-y}{1-y^2}\;dy-3\int_0^1 \frac{y-y^2}{1-y^3}\;dy\\
&=2\ln(2)-3\int_0^1 \frac{y}{1+y+y^2}\;dy\\
&=2\ln(2)-\frac 32\left(\int_0^1 \frac{1+2y}{1+y+y^2}\;dy-\int_0^1 \frac 1{(3/4)+(y+1/2)^2}\;dy\right)\\
&=2\ln(2)-\frac 32\left|\ln(1+y+y^2)-\frac 2{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{1+2y}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right|_0^1\\
&=2\ln(2)-\frac {3\ln(3)}2+\sqrt{3}\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)\\
\end{align}
Adding $1$ from $(2)$ we get again the result $(3)$ :
$$\boxed{\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6j^2-5j+1}=1+2\ln(2)-\frac{3\ln(3)}2+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: Remarkably, the numerical value is very close to $\pi^2/6$.

Comment: Good observation @André : this could be the source of the confusion (even if for me this is far from $\zeta(2)=1.644934066848226\cdots$ :-)). Btw note that the wished $\pi^2/36-1$ is negative for a sum of positive terms...

Comment: Above answer may be correct but, there is included notion of digamma function. Seems to me that series is related to Basel problem.

Comment: @AdiDani: If the denominator was $6(j+n)^2$ with $n$ a positive integer then we would get a $\frac {\pi^2}{36}$ term. With $6(j+n/2)^2$ we would get a $\frac {\pi^2}{12}$ but these denominators are far from the actual one.
Perhaps that the answer simply doesn't correspond to the question...